# Accurately extract frames every N seconds using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, cuda

#### The Usage

I extract images from videos using `ffmpeg`.

I dump one down-scaled image every 10 seconds, inclusive, that I combine into montages with `imagemagick`. These montages again are used to show a preview from the video when hovering the scrubber in a web-based video player. (Calculating which image in the montage to show).

#### The Command

After playing around I ended up with the following command where the idea is speed over quality:

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -loglevel error \
    -hwaccel cuvid \
    -hwaccel_output_format cuda \
    -c:v h264_cuvid \
    -i "$video_file" \
    -r 0.1 \
    -filter:v "scale_cuda=w=-1:h=100,thumbnail_cuda=2,hwdownload,format=nv12" \
    -color_range 2 \
    f%09d.jpg
```

This seemed to work fine. The shots are off by about ± 0.5 - 1 sec here and there, but that is livable.

#### The Problem

Issue is that `ffmpeg` produces one extra image at start of videos. E.g. files are:

```
file             time
f000000001.jpg   00:00:00
f000000002.jpg   00:00:00
f000000003.jpg   00:00:10
f000000004.jpg   00:00:20
f000000005.jpg   00:00:30
...
```

Sometimes first and second is off by a few milliseconds.

As I know it (now) I can simply delete the first image and proceed with the rest, but not sure why this happens and if it is a bug or something else.

Put another way: I need to know if the "effect" of two first frames are *reliable* so that I can delete it in other versions of `ffmpeg` as well.

As I use the images to show 10 sec. snapshot from the video at a specified time *it is off by 10 seconds* if I do not delete first image generated. If for some reason it should then *not* create a dupe at start, other version or what ever, deleting the first image would create the same issue.

#### Montage

*(If of interest the montages are created something like):*

```
montage -tile 5x -geometry +0+0 -background none [file1  - file50 ]  montage01.jpg
montage -tile 5x -geometry +0+0 -background none [file51 - file100]  montage02.jpg
...
```

---

#### Command I use now based on answer (shell):

```sh
# Set on call or global:
file_in=sample.mp4
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
sec_snap_interval=10
nr_start=1
pfx_out=snap


ffmpeg \
    -loglevel warning \
    -hwaccel cuvid \
    -hwaccel_output_format cuda \
    -c:v h264_cuvid \
    -i "$file_in" \
    -pix_fmt "$pix_fmt" \
    -filter:v "
        scale_cuda=
            w = -1 :
            h = 100,
        thumbnail_cuda = 2,
        hwdownload,
        format = nv12,
        select = 'bitor(
            gte(t - prev_selected_t, $sec_snap_interval),
            isnan(prev_selected_t)
        )'
    " \
    -vsync passthrough \
    -color_range 2 \
    -start_number "$nr_start" \
    "$pfx_out%09d.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-r 0.1` sets the output framerate to 0.1Hz, but it's not guaranteed to get frame from the input video exactly every 10 seconds (I am not sure why).

One way for solving it is using [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-select_002c-aselect).

Example (without GPU acceleration):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=bitor(gte(t-prev_selected_t\,10)\,isnan(prev_selected_t))" -vsync 0 f%09d.jpg
```

---

- `bitor(gte(t-prev_selected_t\,10)` is `1` when difference between "passed" timestamps is grater of equal 10 seconds.
  When expression is evaluated to `1`, the frame is "selected" and passed to the output.
- `bitor` with `isnan(prev_selected_t)` passes the first frame, where `prev_selected_t` is `NaN` (has no value).
- `-vsync 0` applies "passthrough" - Each frame is passed with its timestamp from the demuxer to the muxer.

---

Here is an example with `scale_cuda` and `thumbnail_cuda`:

```
ffmpeg \
    -loglevel error \
    -hwaccel cuvid \
    -hwaccel_output_format cuda \
    -c:v h264_cuvid \
    -i "$video_file" \
    -filter:v "scale_cuda=w=-1:h=100,thumbnail_cuda=2,hwdownload,format=nv12,select=bitor(gte(t-prev_selected_t\,10)\,isnan(prev_selected_t))" \
    -vsync 0 \
    -color_range 2 \
    f%09d.jpg
```

- Due to the usage of `thumbnail_cuda` filter, we have to place the `select` filter at the end.

---

Testing:
Build synthetic video with frame counter at 10fps:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=128x72:rate=1:duration=1000 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4
```

---

Output frames after executing the above command:

[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]
[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

As you can see, the selected frames are exactly every 10 seconds.

Comment: Simply awesome  . Though it does not address the question *"why is first image a duplicate"* (or perhaps I'm missing something) - this is better as it 1) does not create a dupe at first "frame". 2) is spot on accurate 3) does not have any (big/any) speed penalty – Only wish I dug into this before processing 4,000+ hours of video haha.

Comment: I could change the title to reflect answer more. E.g. something like **How to extract frames at exact time-intervals with or w/o cuda?** – but there are perhaps duplicates of that. Have not found any with this solution, but my SE search skills are flawed.

Comment: You're welcome. "extracting frames every N seconds" is great - there is a chance that someone finds the post in Google. You have a spelling mistake: replace **evey** with **every**. "Why is first image a duplicate?" is a good question, but I don't know the answer... According to the documentation "vsync is deprecated". Maybe there is a solution using `-fps_mode`.

Comment: I'm on ffmpeg version N-107017 and it is there. I did a more through check and it looks like there is some offset added per frame. E.g. at the `01:00:00` mark the snapshot is from around `01:00:03`, at `01:30:00` it's around `01:30:05` etc. Now the pedant in me has awoken and I have to look more at it :P Same both for the cuda and non cuda method.

Comment: OK. I ended up writing it in JavaScript. Got the time used reduced with about 65% + the shots are off by 0.05 sec or there about at most :) – it is a lot more heavy on the CPU though. Have not bothered with JS / GPU. Considering it produces finished montages the time reduction is even more.